# Authenticating for findsequence service requests HERE Maps API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm attempting to make a GET request from the HERE Maps API service `FindSequence`. I noticed that in the [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/api-reference-findsequence.html), it includes three authentication parameters: `app_id`, `app_code`, `apiKey`. The docs insinuate that there is an option to use an `app_id` and `app_code` combination or an `apiKey` alone. This makes sense because elsewhere in the HERE Maps docs, it's noted that the old pattern was to use `app_id` and `app_code` but that has been recently deprecated and now one is supposed to use `apiKey` alone. In fact, you can not even generate an `app_code` anymore in the HERE developer projects dashboard.

So I attempted to make a request with the `apiKey` but I got an authentication error that demanded the `app_id` and `app_code`:

```
`curl --location --request GET "https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?apiKey=[apiKey]`

{"faultCode":"s74149e0f-5b37-41b1-bf25-0d5f93e06938","responseCode":"400","message":"The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id and app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at http://developer.here.com/myapps."}
```

It's my understanding that freemium accounts do not have customer reps. I've asked for technical help and they send me to Stack Overflow. I followed the url `http://developer.here.com/myapps` but it redirects to `https://developer.here.com/projects`. There is no way to obtain the `app_code` from this url, as far as I can see.

My question is:
1) Do I need to supply an `app_code`? If not, how do I make a request without one? If I do need an `app_code`, how do I obtain one?
2) If `app_code`s can no longer be obtained, is there another service or another version of this service I should be using to calculate the optimal route sequence with given waypoint locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the API key, you need to make sure to query the newer endpoints, in `*.hereapi.com`.

So the following request should work better:

```sh
curl --location --request GET "https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json?apiKey=[apiKey]&param1=value1&...
```